# capturing and cancelling the new window opening event in a wpf web browser

Tags: c#, wpf

Can any one please tell me how to cancel the event of new window opening in a wpf webbrowser in C#?I dont want to show the internet explorer window on top of my application when a link is clicked.

The webbrowser is defined as below:

```
  <WebBrowser Canvas.Left="311.522" Canvas.Top="106.949" Height="500.805"
                  Width="945.998" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="wbNavigator" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ClipToBounds="True"   Navigated="wbNavigator_Navigated" />
```

Regards,

Comment: Could you show your hyperlink declaration in XAML?

Comment: hyperlink is coming as part of google maps. I have edited the question to accomodate the webbrowser tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, scroll to the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). One of the users provides a solution that involves getting the IWebBrowser2 interface from the WPF WebBrowser control. This interface provides access to the NewWindow event, which can be used to cancel the opening of a new browser window. It seems like a valid solution to me.

Good luck and let me know if you need any more help with this.

Comment: For reference: the URL has changed and can now be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you post the solution here? Just providing a link is not good and doesn't help directly and is not conform with stackoverflow rules.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your namespace works for me, I don't know why ... I found it [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22943.preventing-external-links-from-opening-in-new-window-in-wpf-web-browser.aspx)
but I have used only this part of the code without **MyWebBrowser.LoadCompleted** and COM references stuffs

```
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa")]
internal interface IServiceProvider
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
    object QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid);
}
```

If someone can explain why this code do the job, please...